# passing multiple command options using ROBOT SSH library

Tags: robotframework

```
I am new to RF and trying to autmoate user account on test machine.
Once the main command nmc@myhost:/$ "create appliance user john" is executed
it will ask for multiple inputs one by one with enter key press in each level. 
I tried with write and read keywords of SSH as below and not able to get success.
```

Manual test execution output.
    ============================
    nmc@myhost:/$ create appliance user john
    Home folder         : JOHN/Test
    Description         : test
    Default group       : staff
    Password            : xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Confirm password    : xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    nmc@myhost:/$

```
    enter code here



*** Settings ***
Suite Setup       Open Connection And Log In
Suite Teardown    Close All Connections
Library           SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***
${HOST}           192.168.221.129
${USERNAME}       admin
${PASSWORD}       nexenta

*** Test Cases ***
User_Create
    ${written}=    Write    nmc -c "create appliance user john"
    Set Client Configuration    prompt=:    timeout=60s
    ${output}=    Read Until prompt
    ${written}=    Write    John/Test
    ${output}=    Read Until prompt
    ${written}=    Write    Test
    ${output}=    Read Until prompt
    ${written}=    Write    staff
    ${output}=    Read Until prompt
    ${written}=    Write    afghg@12345
    ${output}=    Read Until prompt
    ${written}=    Write    afghg@12345
    ${output}=    Read Until    $

*** Keywords ***
Open Connection And Log In
    Set Log Level    DEBUG
    Open Connection    ${HOST}    timeout=1 hour
    Login    ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
```

Comment: Can you provide a full [mcve] for your issue? Presently I'm missing which libraries are used and what is actually happening, as opposed to what you expect. (that part is clear). Also any description of things you've tried will be helpful.

Comment: I am trying to automate user create test case on nexenta appliance. The command which i tried is "create appliance create user". which takes multiple options like "username", home folder, description, usergroup selection,  password,confirm password one by one . I am stuck in how to pass these options to the main command one by one . I am using ROBOT framework SSH  external library. I tried using write and read combination and no success. Pls help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the full example of your code? It will provide us with a better overview of the conditions the script is running.